# Select similar pixels, draw bezier path around pixels and fill with color - iOS

Tags: objective-c, colors, uiimage, pixel, uibezierpath

Assume a jpg with colored shapes on a black bg. Some of the shapes touch. I want to tap on a shape, and then select all pixels of similar color and outline and fill on a new layer in same position. Could be a uiview, could be a uiimage.

Direction on similar color selection and outline fill appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad as stated right now. You should first attempt to solve the problem and then ask more concrete questions about the parts of your solution that you are having trouble with.

Comment: https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill - you can use this algorithm to solve this else you have to use this https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage to modify shaders as for your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the same problem but similar: my application needed to create a Bezier path around the edge of icons with transparent backgrounds. Really, the only big difference between these two problems is the criteria you choose to determine which pixels are part of the "shape" and which aren't.

The algorithm uses a simple technique called Moore-Nieghbor tracing. In essence, imagine a blind person walking around the edge of a building, keeping one hand on the wall, until they come back to their starting location. The resulting path is an outline of the building.

This code is a tad more complicated because I introduce an "inset" value that effectively shrinks the outline N pixels; I do this so at higher resolutions the path draws over the edge of the icon, rather than outside it. It should be easy to bypass this code if you don't need that.

My solution is based on a structure called `SystemIconBuffer` that holds multiple resolutions of an icon. You can basically ignore all of that. The important step is to rasterize your image into an array (I use `CGBitmatContextCreate`) of RGBA bytes and get a pointer to that array in `srcBuffer`.

Finally, my images are always square, so my code only has one dimension value (`dim`) which you'd need to convert into `dimX` and `dimY`, for a rectangular image.

And again, my code is only interested in finding the transparent edge of the image so it's only looking at the "alpha" component of each pixel. Adjust your criteria as needed.

And without further ado...

```
// Based on Moore-Nieghbor tracing
//  <http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html>
//  <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood>

// RGBA buffers store each pixel value as four sequential 8-bit integers
// The outline trace is interested only in the alpha component, and uses the other three bytes for intermediate values
#define kAlphaOffset        3
#define kBlackOffset        0       // reuse R to record if this pixel is considered to be "black"
#define kVisitedOffset      2       // reuse G to record if this pixel has been visited

#define kIsBodyAlphaThreshold   (255/20)    // a pixel with > 5% opacity is considered to be "black" (part of the image)

// Notes: all of these functions assume a square image buffer exactly dim x dim x RGBA
//        all functions clip x & y to valid pixels addresses in the buffer and ignore anything outside
static NSUInteger GetValue( NSInteger x, NSInteger y, NSUInteger offset, const UInt8* buffer, NSInteger dim );
static void FillSquareOfValues( NSInteger x, NSInteger y, NSInteger size, NSUInteger value, NSUInteger offset, UInt8* buffer, NSInteger dim );

#define kNeighbors      8   // each pixel has eight Moore neighbors
// The x & y offset of neighboring pixels, starting with the pixel immediately above the pixel and moving clockwise around it
enum {
    kUpNeighbor = 0,
    kUpperRightNeighbor,
    kRightNeighbor,
    kLowerRightNeighbor,
    kDownNeighbor,
    kLowerLeftNeighbor,
    kLeftNeighbor,
    kUpperLeftNeighbor
};
static NSInteger NeighborX[kNeighbors] = { 0,  1,  1,  1,  0, -1, -1, -1 };     // coordinate offsets of neighbor directions
static NSInteger NeighborY[kNeighbors] = { 1,  1,  0, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1 };
static NSUInteger EntryDirection[kNeighbors] = {        // translates the neighboring pixel hit into an entry direction
    kRightNeighbor,             // above
    kRightNeighbor,             // upper right
    kDownNeighbor,              // right
    kDownNeighbor,              // lower right
    kLeftNeighbor,              // below
    kLeftNeighbor,              // lower left
    kUpNeighbor,                // left
    kUpNeighbor };              // upper left
#define OppositeDirection(DIRECTION)    ((DIRECTION+4)&0x07)    // macro to calculate the opposite neighbor position or direction

- (NSInteger)edgeIndentForSize:(IconSizeSelector)selector
{
    // the inset of black pixels from any transparent pixel for a given icon size
    // right now it's aribrarily the pixel size selector, so mini icons get no
    //  indent, large get 1 pixel, huge gets 2 pixels, ...
    return (NSInteger)selector;
}

- (NSBezierPath*)outlineFromBuffer:(SystemIconBuffer*)buffer forSize:(IconSizeSelector)selector
{
    // Get the array of RGBA pixels for the source image
    // Do this before locking drawBufferLock becuase -dataForSize might need to convert an NSImage into
    //  a pixel buffer, and it will need IconFrameBuffer() to do that
    const UInt8* srcBuffer = [buffer dataForSize:selector].bytes;

    // Aquire a temporary frame buffer to use for the calculations
    OSSpinLockLock(&drawBufferLock);
    UInt8* pixels = IconFrameBuffer(selector);
    bzero(pixels,IconRGBABufferSize(selector));     // fill buffer with zeros

    NSInteger dim = IconPixelIntegerSize[selector];

    // Determine the "black" pixels of the image. This is done by setting all of the pixels to "black" (true) and then erasing
    //  a range of them near any transparent pixels in the source image. The size of the range is determined by edgeIndent.
    //  When edgeIndent is non-zero, the black pixels are required to be a least that many pixels away from any transparent
    //  pixel, effectively insetting the image from its edges.
    NSInteger edgeIdent = [self edgeIndentForSize:selector];
    // Paint the whole pixel map "black"
    FillSquareOfValues(0,0,dim,1,kBlackOffset,pixels,dim);
    // Scan all of the pixels (including one row & column of phantom pixels beyond the edge of the image) looking for
    //  transparent pixels. If found, erase the black pixel at that coordinate plus all pixels within edgeIndent of it.
    for ( NSInteger x=-1; x<=dim; x++ )
        for (NSInteger y=-1; y<=dim; y++ )
            if (GetValue(x,y,kAlphaOffset,srcBuffer,dim)<=kIsBodyAlphaThreshold)
                // fill with not-black values at x,y plus edgeIndent pixels adjacent to it
                FillSquareOfValues(x-edgeIdent,y-edgeIdent,edgeIdent*2+1,0,kBlackOffset,pixels,dim);

    // Find the starting pixel
    NSInteger startX = -1;
    NSInteger startY = -1;
    // Scanning left to right, bottom to top, find the first lower-left(ish) pixel
    for ( NSInteger x=0; x<dim; x++ )
        for ( NSInteger y=0; y<dim; y++ )
            if (GetValue(x, y, kBlackOffset, pixels, dim)!=0)
                {
                startX = x;
                startY = y;
                x = y = dim;    // break both loops
                }

    // Create the path and set the start point
    NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    if (startX<0 && startY<0)
        goto bail;              // there are no opaque pixels: return an empty path
    [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(startX+0.5,startY+0.5)];

    // Determine initial entry direction for first pixel
    // Conceptually, we'd want to walk around this pixel counter-clockwise to find the next-to-the-last pixel
    //  in the outline, which will tell us the direction the last edge pixel will (re)enter this one.
    // However ...
    // Because we "snuck" up on the first pixel by scanning columns left to right, we know that there are no
    //  black pixels immeidately below it or to its left. The only variable is whether there are pixels to its right and
    //  whether they are above or below it. Ultimately, we only need to test one configuration. If there
    //  are no pixels to the immediate right or lower-right, then the final entry direction will be from
    //  the right (6). If there are pixels in either of these locations, the final entry direction will be
    //  from the bottom (0).
    NSUInteger initialEntryDirection = 0;
    if (GetValue(startX+1,startY-1,kBlackOffset,pixels,dim)==0 && GetValue(startX+1,startY,kBlackOffset,pixels,dim)==0)
        initialEntryDirection = 6;

    // Start the outline trace
    // At each pixel, starting with the pixel in the opposite direction of the entry direction, test the pixels,
    //  clockwise, until we find the next black pixel adjacent to this one. Add it to the outline and repeat
    //  until we encounter the first pixel again, entered from the same direction (Jacob's stopping criterion).
    NSInteger x = startX;
    NSInteger lastX = x;
    NSInteger y = startY;
    NSInteger lastY = y;
    NSUInteger direction = initialEntryDirection;
    do {
        // Search, clockwise, for the next neighboring black pixel
        NSInteger nextX, nextY;
        NSUInteger nextDir = OppositeDirection(direction);
        do {
            // Progress to the next neighbor direction (note that when first entering the loop we always
            //  know that the pixel we entered from must be white, or we couldn't have entered from that direction,
            //  so the entry pixel never needs to be tested)
            nextDir += 1;
            if (nextDir>kNeighbors*2)
                // Safety check: an image with a single, isolated, pixel will cause this loop to run forever
                goto bail;
            nextX = x+NeighborX[nextDir&0x07];
            nextY = y+NeighborY[nextDir&0x07];
        } while (GetValue(nextX,nextY,kBlackOffset,pixels,dim)==0);
        // Loop exits with [nextX,nextY] of next clockwise black pixel and the direction of that pixel relative to this one
        x = nextX;                              // move to this point
        y = nextY;
        direction = EntryDirection[nextDir&0x07];   // translate pixel relative direction into entry direction

        if (x!=lastX || y!=lastY)
            {
            // This is a new point in the list: add it to the path
            [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(x+0.5,y+0.5)];
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            }
    } while (x!=startX || y!=startY || direction!=initialEntryDirection);
    // Loop will exit when the countour has been traced back to its orignal point
bail:
    [path closePath];

    OSSpinLockUnlock(&drawBufferLock);
    return path;
}

static NSUInteger GetValue( NSInteger x, NSInteger y, NSUInteger offset, const UInt8* buffer, NSInteger dim )
{
    if (x>=0 && x<dim && y>=0 && y<dim )
        return buffer[((dim-y-1)*dim+x)*4+offset];
    return 0;
}

static void FillSquareOfValues( NSInteger x, NSInteger y, NSInteger size, NSUInteger value, NSUInteger offset, UInt8* buffer, NSInteger dim )
{
    NSInteger endX = MIN(x+size,dim);
    NSInteger endY = MIN(y+size,dim);
    if (x<0) x = 0;
    if (y<0) y = 0;
    for ( NSInteger i=x; i<endX; i++ )
        for ( NSInteger j=y; j<endY; j++ )
            buffer[((dim-j-1)*dim+i)*4+offset] = value;
}
```

One last note: The resulting bezier path is **not** very efficient because it contains hundreds, if not thousands, of tiny line segments. In my code, I use the resulting path to draw the outline (once) into an off-screen buffer, which I then turn into an cached image that I reuse.

Creating something from this and drawing it is, as they say, left as an exercise for the student...

Answer (score 0):

1. https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill - you can use this algorithm to solve this.
2. you have to use this https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage to modify shaders as for your requirement.